# Get Element bound to beforeunload Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I have a number of widgets loaded onto a widget grid. Each widget has a JavaScript method which will refresh every 'x' seconds. This is done by calling setInterval on the Javascript method for each widget. The setInterval is called against the window:

```
window.[FunctionName] = setInterval(FunctionName, RefreshTime * 1000);
```

where `FunctionName` is the name of the JavaScript method, `RefreshTime` is the time before refreshing in seconds.

On removal of each widget, the name of the Javascript function is found, and the interval is cleared as below:

```
    $(".grid").on("click", ".panel-close", function () {
        var widget = $(this).parent();
        var jscrpt = $(widget).find(".RefreshMethod");
        if (jscrpt.length > 0) {
            window[jscrpt.data("name")] = null;
            clearInterval(window[jscrpt.data("interval")]);
        }
        RemoveWidget(widget);
    })
```

Since the `jscrpt` element has the `name` attribute the name of the method can be found and the interval cleared when the widget is removed, preventing further refreshing. This works well.

However, if the page is ajax loaded and the entire grid of widgets is removed, there is no remove event. I begun investigating using the `beforeunload` event as below:

```
    $(".grid .widget").bind("beforeunload", function (event) {
        var widget = $(this);
        var jscrpt = $(widget).find(".RefreshMethod");
        if (jscrpt.length > 0) {
            window[jscrpt.data("name")] = null;
            clearInterval(window[jscrpt.data("interval")]);
        }
    })
```

This function is called when the elements are about to be cleared. This works when the widget is removed or if the elements are overwritten. However, using `$(this)` does not work - the object is a "beforeunload" type object. `event` is also undefined - I can't see anyway of identifying which widget is being unloaded.

The question is, when I bind the `beforeunload` function to an element, when the function is triggered how do I identify which element has triggered the function?

Comment: Is the `beforeunload` event explicitly triggered by the `.grid` and/or `.widget`? Otherwise this event will only be fired when the `window` and its resources are unloaded.

Comment: No - but the event is still triggered. Note that the beforeunload event isn't bound to the window, so when the .widget element is about to be unloaded, the event is triggered. The issue is identifying which element triggered the event. For example, I have widgets 1,2 and 3. I unload widget 2 - how do I identify if I just unloaded widget 2 as opposed to 1 or 3?

Comment: No, [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload) is only fired by the `window` - http://jsfiddle.net/y16cp4gd/

Comment: This has now opened a whole new round of questions. I'm adding this code to an existing web application - I'm not sure why it works for me, but it does. If I put a breakpoint in my beforeunload function, it hits every time I remove a widget or overwrite the grid. I'll need to do some more investigation here.

Comment: _"...if the page is ajax loaded..."_ Can't you just remove all timers on start of the ajax request? Something like `$(document).ajaxStart(function() { $(".RefreshMethod").each(function() { clearInterval(window[$(this).data("name")]); }); })`

Comment: That might be possible with a bit of work - but loading a widget is an ajax load itself - we would need to identify that the ajax load is reloading the page content, not just a small segment.